# Changing an Array of Strings inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

What I'm trying to do is pretty straight forward in other languages. But I'm struggling with this in a C project and didn't find a right way to do it in my researches.

What I need to do is:

1. Declare an global empty array of strings
2. Inside a function I want to populate this global array with X new strings
3. In another function, I want loop through all new elements of this array printing them out.

The code I have now is listed below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *menu[] = {};

void populateMenu(){

    // populate this menu with some itens
    *menu = {
        "New item A",
        "New item B",
        NULL
    };
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // 1. print inicial menu

    int menuAlen = sizeof(menu)/sizeof(*menu);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < menuAlen; i++){
        printf("%s\n", menu[i]);
    }

    // 2. populate the menu
    populateMenu();

    // 3. print it again with new values
    int menuBlen = sizeof(menu)/sizeof(*menu);
    for(i = 0; i < menuBlen; i++){
        printf("%s\n", menu[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently getting this error on build time.

**main.c:16:16: Expected expression**

Line 16 is the first line inside populateMenu function.

Can someone help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Best.
George.

Comment: You can't use an expression like `{ ... }` in an assignment, only in variable initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare `menu` as a pointer to [some array of] pointer strings:

```
char**menu;
```

You need to know the number of menu entries. So declare also

```
size_t nb_menu;
```

and have some way to compute it at *runtime*. (I leave that up to you, but you cannot use `sizeof`  which is a compile-time thing).

You then allocate in the heap, using [calloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html), that array:

```
menu = calloc (nb_menu+1, sizeof(char*));
if (!menu) { perror("calloc menu"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

I'm doing `nb_menu+1` because you probably want to `NULL` terminate your `menu`.

Now you could fill it, e.g.

```
menu[0] = "Some string";
```

or better yet, use [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html).

<sup>You should have a convention (and document it) about when and which pointers are into the heap -i.e; `malloc`-ed or `calloc`-ed and who should `free` them.</sup>

You should later [free(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) your pointers to avoid [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You can only `free` a pointer obtained by `malloc` or `calloc` or `strdup` (which calls `malloc`) etc...

On Linux, you should learn how to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Perhaps using [Boehm Garbage Collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) could help you. Certainly, understand what [garbage collectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) are and learn a lot more about [C memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management).

Actually, you could use [flexible array members](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/flexible-array-member/) and have your `menu` be a pointer to

```
struct menu_st {
  unsigned nb_entries;
  char* entry_array[]; // nb_entries elements in the array
};
```

Read about the [C memory model](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/CS2022/2011sp/lectures/lect06.pdf).

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`). Be very scared of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `calloc` does not generate null pointers if you're on a system where null pointers are not all-bits-zero; so to be more portable, use `malloc` and then assign NULL to each pointer if it's important to do so (OP was using a null-terminated list of pointers so he only needs to set the first one).

Comment: @MattNabb: I agree with you in theory, but can you name today a widely used system with a `NULL` pointer not represented by all-zero bits? I can't!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks a lot for the answer. I managed to get it working following for steps and understating whats actually going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char **menu = NULL;

void populateMenu(){
    static const char *items[] = {
        "New item A",
        "New item B",
        NULL
    };
    menu = items;
}

int menuLen(const char **menu){
    int len = 0;
    if(!menu) return 0;
    while(*menu++)
        ++len;
    return len;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    // 1. print inicial menu

    int menuAlen = menuLen(menu);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < menuAlen; i++){
        printf("%s\n", menu[i]);
    }

    // 2. populate the menu
    populateMenu();

    // 3. print it again with new values
    int menuBlen = menuLen(menu);
    for(i = 0; i < menuBlen; i++){
        printf("%s\n", menu[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Nice approach with the menuLen function. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I hate global variables. I suggest you create the array inside `main()` and pass it throughout your code as needed.

```
// #includes ...
// prototypes
int main(void) {
    char menu[1000][80]; // space for 1000 strings each up to 79 characters long
    size_t nmenu;        // number of string in menu

    nmenu = populate(menu); // change contents of array, set nmenu
    menuprint(menu, nmenu); // print

    return 0;
}
```

The rest of the program (the functions `populate()` and `menuprint()`) is up to you.

Note: the `1000` and `80` are large(ish) estimates. A better way to do it would be with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion actually works. The problem is the device I'm running it into. I'm very constraint in memory, so initialising a 1000 array (or any other var size bigger then I really need) seems a problem to me. But thanks!