# C function to load file contents into string array

Tags: arrays, c, file

What I'm trying to do is this:

1. Properly initiate a 2D char array (array of strings), then,
2. In another function, load the contents of the file to that 2D array, breaking to the next row in the 2D array at each `'\n'` newline character.

Since we cannot return double arrays from functions in C, I'm trying to use `strncpy()`, reading the file line-by-line. I've tried lots of variants, but I keep messing with the memory, so I have faced a lot of segfaults and bus errors.

Here is a model demonstrating how simple what I'm trying to do is:

```c
int main()
{
  char *file_content[];
  load_file_to_array(file_content);
}

void load_file_to_array(char *to_load[]) {
  // something to update file_content
}
```

*EDIT 1*:

I'm not asking anyone to write my code for me. I'm frustrated with researching about this specific topic, so I decided to ask about what you guys think. Any different approach or the methodology itself are appreciated.

I have a good hunch about my approach that it is probably completely off-track.

I've looked at a lot of posts and articles about dynamic memory. The closest thing I have found to what I'm trying to accomplish is this: [Changing an Array of Strings inside a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416160/changing-a-array-of-strings-inside-a-function-in-c)

*EDIT 2:*

As @pm100 explained in the comments, I tried:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 255

void load_array(char *, char *[]);

int main() {
    // NULL terminate array
    char *fn = "text.txt";
    char *arr[MAX_SIZE] = { NULL };
    // Also tried: 
    // char **arr = malloc(sizeof * char*MAX_SIZE)
    // arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_SIZE);
    load_array(fn, arr);
}

void load_array(char *fn, char *fcontent[]) {
    FILE * file = fopen(fn, "r");

    char line[MAX_SIZE];
    
    int i = 0;

    // read file line by line with fgets()
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) 
    {
        // this part I'm not sure of. maybe setting with fgets makes more
        // sense.
        strcpy(fcontent[i], line);
        i++;
        // realloc()
        fcontent = realloc(fcontent, sizeof (char*) * (i + 1));
        fcontent[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_SIZE);
        // null terminate the last line
        *fcontent[i] = 0; 
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

I get a segfault after running the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a model demonstrating how simple what I'm trying to do is:
>
> ```c
> int main()
> {
>   char *file_content[];
>   load_file_to_array(file_content);
> }
>
> void load_file_to_array(char *to_load[]){
>   // something to update file_content
> }
> ```

### Basic usage

Alright, here's an approach that allows you do what you want with 100% *static memory allocation*, which I prefer whenever possible for many reasons (some listed below).

Example usage, to show how simple it is to use:

```c
int main()
{
    // Make this huge struct `static` so that the buffers it contains will be
    // `static` so that they are neither on the stack **nor** the heap, thereby
    // preventing stack overflow in the event you make them larger than the stack
    // size, which is ~7.4 MB for Linux. See my answer here:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/64085509/4561887.
    static file_t file;

    const char FILENAME[] = "path/to/some/file.txt";
    // OR:
    // const char FILENAME[] = __FILE__; // read this source code file itself
    file_store_path(&file, FILENAME);

    printf("Loading file at path \"%s\".\n", file.path);
    // open the file and copy its entire contents into the `file` object
    file_load(&file);

    printf("Printing the entire file:\n");
    file_print_all(&file);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing just this 1 line number:\n");
    file_print_line(&file, 256);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing 4 lines starting at this line number:\n");
    file_print_lines(&file, 256, 4);
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

### How does it work?

I don't use any 2D arrays or anything. Rather, I create a static 1D array of chars as `char file_str[MAX_NUM_CHARS];`, which contains all chars from the entire file, and I create a static 1D array of `char *` (ptr to `char`) as `char* line_array[MAX_NUM_LINES];`, which contains pointers to the first char of each line in the entire file, where the chars these pointers are pointing to are *inside the `file_str` array.* Then, I read the file one char at a time into the `file_str` array. Each time I see a `\n` newline char I know that the next char is the start of a new line, so I add a ptr to that char into the `line_array` array.

To print the file back out I iterate through the `line_array` array, printing all chars from each line, one line at a time.

One could choose to get rid of the `line_array` array entirely and just use the `file_str` character array. You could still choose a line to print and print it. The drawback of that approach, however, is that finding the start of the line to print would take **O(n)** time since you'd have to start at the first `char` in the file and read all the way through it to the line of interest, counting lines by counting the number of newline `\n` chars you see. My approach, on the other hand, takes **O(1)** time and indexes straight to the front of the line of interest through a simple index into the `line_array` array.

The arrays above are stored in a `file_t` struct, defined as follows:

```c
#define MAX_NUM_LINES 10000UL
#define MAX_NUM_CHARS (MAX_NUM_LINES*200UL) // 2 MB
#define MAX_PATH_LEN (1000)

typedef struct file_s
{
    /// The path to the file to open.
    char path[MAX_PATH_LEN];

    /// All characters read from the file.
    char file_str[MAX_NUM_CHARS];     // array of `char`

    /// The total number of chars read into the `file_str` string, including
    //  null terminator.
    size_t num_chars;

    /// A ptr to each line in the file.
    char* line_array[MAX_NUM_LINES];  // array of `char*` (ptr to char)

    /// The total number of lines in the file, and hence in the `line_array`
    //  above.
    size_t num_lines;
} file_t;
```

Here are some stats I print out about `file_t` at the beginning of my program:

> The size of the `file_t` struct is 2081016 bytes (2.081016 MB; 1.984612 MiB).
> Max file size that can be read into this struct is 2000000 bytes or 10000 lines, whichever limit is hit first.

The `file` object is static so that if you ever make your `file_t` struct really huge to handle massive files (many gigabytes even, if you wanted), you don't have a stack overflow, since thread stack sizes are limited to ~7.4 MB for Linux. See my answer here: [C/C++ maximum stack size of program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64085509/4561887).

**I use static memory allocation, not dynamic, for these reasons:**

1. It's faster at run-time since lots of dynamic memory allocation can add substantial overhead.
2. It's deterministic to use static memory allocation, making this implementation style good for
   safety-critical, memory-constrained, real-time, deterministic, embedded devices and programs.
3. It can access the first character of any line in the file in O(1) time via a simple index into
   an array.
4. It's extensible via dynamic memory allocation if needed (more on this below).

The file is opened and loaded into the `file` object via the `file_load()` function. That function looks like this, including with robust error handling:

```c
/// Read all characters from a file on your system at the path specified in the
/// file object and copy this file data **into** the passed-in `file` object.
void file_load(file_t* file)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): NULL ptr.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    FILE* fp = fopen(file->path, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): Failed to open file (%s).\n",
            __func__, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    // See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc
    int c; // note: int, not char, required to handle EOF
    size_t i_write_char = 0;
    size_t i_write_line = 0;
    bool start_of_line = true;
    const size_t I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX = ARRAY_LEN(file->file_str) - 1;
    const size_t I_WRITE_LINE_MAX = ARRAY_LEN(file->line_array) - 1;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) // standard C I/O file reading loop
    {
        // 1. Write the char
        if (i_write_char > I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX)
        {
            printf("ERROR in function %s(): file is full (i_write_char = "
                   "%zu, but I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX is only %zu).\n",
                   __func__, i_write_char, I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX);
            break;
        }
        file->file_str[i_write_char] = c;

        // 2. Write the ptr to the line
        if (start_of_line)
        {
            start_of_line = false;

            if (i_write_line > I_WRITE_LINE_MAX)
            {
                printf("ERROR in function %s(): file is full (i_write_line = "
                       "%zu, but I_WRITE_LINE_MAX is only %zu).\n",
                       __func__, i_write_line, I_WRITE_LINE_MAX);
                break;
            }
            file->line_array[i_write_line] = &(file->file_str[i_write_char]);
            i_write_line++;
        }

        // end of line
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            // '\n' indicates the end of a line, so prepare to start a new line
            // on the next iteration
            start_of_line = true;
        }

        i_write_char++;
    }

    file->num_chars = i_write_char;
    file->num_lines = i_write_line;

    fclose(fp);
}
```

### Extend it via dynamic memory allocation

In many cases, the above static memory allocation above is sufficient. It is good to avoid dynamic memory allocation whenever possible. However, if you're going to use dynamic memory allocation, do *not* allocate tons of small chunks! It's better to allocate one or two big chunks instead. Speed test this to prove it--always verify what people say--myself included! As evidence of this, though, read this too and look at the plot: https://github.com/facontidavide/CPP_Optimizations_Diary/blob/master/docs/reserve.md. "NoReserve" is with lots of small dynamic memory allocations and *subsequent memory copies of existing data into these new memory locations*, and "WithReserve" is with one single large dynamic memory allocation up-front instead:
[image]

Sometimes dynamic memory allocation *is* prudent, however. How can we best do it? Let's say you needed to open 1000 files and have them all open at the same time, with file sizes ranging from a few bytes to a few GB. In that case, using static memory allocation for all 1000 files would be not only bad, but *nearly impossible* (at the least, awkward and space-inefficient). What you should do instead is make `file_t` large enough to hold even the largest file of a few GB in size, but then *statically allocate one instance of it to use as a buffer*, and then do this: after opening each file (one at a time) and loading it into a *single* `file` object you have, dynamically `malloc()` the *exact* amount of memory you need for that file, and `strncpy()` or `memcpy()` all the data over from that initial static `file` object into a dynamic object which has the exact amount of memory the file needs, with no waste. In this way, the static `file` object is just there as a placeholder, or buffer, to read the file, counting the number of bytes and number of lines at the same time, so you can then dynamically allocate just enough memory for those bytes and lines.

### Full code

Here is the full code. This program opens up the source code file itself and prints it all out, printing line numbers at the start of each line just for fun.

**[read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c)**, from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`
#include <string.h>  // for `strerror()`


// Get the number of elements in any C array
// - Usage example: [my own answer]:
//   https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80236/initializing-array-of-structs/80289#80289
#define ARRAY_LEN(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

/// Max and min gcc/clang **statement expressions** (safer than macros) for C. By Gabriel Staples.
/// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532788/4561887
#define MAX(a, b)               \
    ({                          \
        __typeof__(a) _a = (a); \
        __typeof__(b) _b = (b); \
        _a > _b ? _a : _b;      \
    })
#define MIN(a, b)               \
    ({                          \
        __typeof__(a) _a = (a); \
        __typeof__(b) _b = (b); \
        _a < _b ? _a : _b;      \
    })

/// Bytes per megabyte
#define BYTES_PER_MB (1000*1000)
/// Bytes per mebibyte
#define BYTES_PER_MIB (1024*1024)

/// Convert bytes to megabytes
#define BYTES_TO_MB(bytes) (((double)(bytes))/BYTES_PER_MB)
/// Convert bytes to mebibytes
#define BYTES_TO_MIB(bytes) (((double)(bytes))/BYTES_PER_MIB)

#define MAX_NUM_LINES 10000UL
#define MAX_NUM_CHARS (MAX_NUM_LINES*200UL) // 2 MB
#define MAX_PATH_LEN (1000)

typedef struct file_s
{
    /// The path to the file to open.
    char path[MAX_PATH_LEN];

    /// All characters read from the file.
    char file_str[MAX_NUM_CHARS];     // array of `char`

    /// The total number of chars read into the `file_str` string, including
    //  null terminator.
    size_t num_chars;

    /// A ptr to each line in the file.
    char* line_array[MAX_NUM_LINES];  // array of `char*` (ptr to char)

    /// The total number of lines in the file, and hence in the `line_array`
    //  above.
    size_t num_lines;
} file_t;

/// Copy the file path pointed to by `path` into the `file_t` object.
void file_store_path(file_t* file, const char *path)
{
    if (file == NULL || path == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): NULL ptr.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    strncpy(file->path, path, sizeof(file->path));
}

/// Print the entire line at 1-based line number `line_number` in file `file`, including the
/// '\n' at the end of the line.
void file_print_line(const file_t* file, size_t line_number)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): NULL ptr.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    // Ensure we don't read outside the `file->line_array`
    if (line_number > file->num_lines)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): line_number (%zu) is too large (file->num_lines = %zu).\n",
            __func__, line_number, file->num_lines);
        return;
    }

    size_t i_line = line_number - 1;
    char* line = file->line_array[i_line];
    if (line == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = %zu at "
               "index = %zu.\n", __func__, line_number, i_line);
        return;
    }

    // print all chars in the line
    size_t i_char = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (i_char > file->num_chars - 1)
        {
            // outside valid data
            break;
        }

        char c = line[i_char];
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            printf("%c", c);
            break;
        }
        else if (c == '\0')
        {
            // null terminator
            break;
        }

        printf("%c", c);
        i_char++;
    }
}

/// Print `num_lines` number of lines in a file, starting at 1-based line number `first_line`,
/// and including the '\n' at the end of each line.
/// At the start of each line, the line number is also printed, followed by a colon (:).
void file_print_lines(const file_t* file, size_t first_line, size_t num_lines)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): NULL ptr.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    if (num_lines == 0 || file->num_lines == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): num_lines passed in == %zu; file->num_lines = %zu.\n",
            __func__, num_lines, file->num_lines);
        return;
    }

    // Ensure we don't read outside the valid data
    size_t last_line = MIN(first_line + num_lines - 1, file->num_lines);
    // printf("last_line = %zu\n", last_line); // DEBUGGING
    for (size_t line_number = first_line; line_number <= last_line; line_number++)
    {
        printf("%4lu: ", line_number);
        file_print_line(file, line_number);
    }
}

/// Print an entire file.
void file_print_all(const file_t* file)
{
    printf("num_chars to print = %zu\n", file->num_chars);
    printf("num_lines to print = %zu\n", file->num_lines);
    printf("========== FILE START ==========\n");
    file_print_lines(file, 1, file->num_lines);
    printf("=========== FILE END ===========\n");
}

/// Read all characters from a file on your system at the path specified in the
//  file object.
void file_load(file_t* file)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): NULL ptr.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    FILE* fp = fopen(file->path, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in function %s(): Failed to open file (%s).\n",
            __func__, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    // See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc
    int c; // note: int, not char, required to handle EOF
    size_t i_write_char = 0;
    size_t i_write_line = 0;
    bool start_of_line = true;
    const size_t I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX = ARRAY_LEN(file->file_str) - 1;
    const size_t I_WRITE_LINE_MAX = ARRAY_LEN(file->line_array) - 1;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) // standard C I/O file reading loop
    {
        // 1. Write the char
        if (i_write_char > I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX)
        {
            printf("ERROR in function %s(): file is full (i_write_char = "
                   "%zu, but I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX is only %zu).\n",
                   __func__, i_write_char, I_WRITE_CHAR_MAX);
            break;
        }
        file->file_str[i_write_char] = c;

        // 2. Write the ptr to the line
        if (start_of_line)
        {
            start_of_line = false;

            if (i_write_line > I_WRITE_LINE_MAX)
            {
                printf("ERROR in function %s(): file is full (i_write_line = "
                       "%zu, but I_WRITE_LINE_MAX is only %zu).\n",
                       __func__, i_write_line, I_WRITE_LINE_MAX);
                break;
            }
            file->line_array[i_write_line] = &(file->file_str[i_write_char]);
            i_write_line++;
        }

        // end of line
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            // '\n' indicates the end of a line, so prepare to start a new line
            // on the next iteration
            start_of_line = true;
        }

        i_write_char++;
    }

    file->num_chars = i_write_char;
    file->num_lines = i_write_line;

    fclose(fp);
}

// Make this huge struct `static` so that the buffers it contains will be `static` so that they are
// neither on the stack **nor** the heap, thereby preventing stack overflow in the event you make
// them larger than the stack size, which is ~7.4 MB for Linux, and are generally even smaller for other systems. See my answer here:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/64085509/4561887.
static file_t file;

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("The size of the `file_t` struct is %zu bytes (%.6f MB; %.6f MiB).\n"
           "Max file size that can be read into this struct is %zu bytes or %lu lines, whichever "
           "limit is hit first.\n\n",
           sizeof(file_t), BYTES_TO_MB(sizeof(file_t)), BYTES_TO_MIB(sizeof(file_t)),
           sizeof(file.file_str), ARRAY_LEN(file.line_array));

    const char FILENAME[] = __FILE__;
    file_store_path(&file, FILENAME);

    printf("Loading file at path \"%s\".\n", file.path);
    // open the file and copy its entire contents into the `file` object
    file_load(&file);

    printf("Printing the entire file:\n");
    file_print_all(&file);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing just this 1 line number:\n");
    file_print_line(&file, 256);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing 4 lines starting at this line number:\n");
    file_print_lines(&file, 256, 4);
    printf("\n");

    // FOR TESTING: intentionally cause some errors by trying to print some lines for an unpopulated
    // file object. Example errors:
    //      243: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 243 at index = 242.
    //      244: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 244 at index = 243.
    //      245: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 245 at index = 244.
    //      246: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 246 at index = 245.
    // Note: for kicks (since I didn't realize this was possible), I'm also using the variable name
    // `$` for this `file_t` object.
    printf("Causing some intentional errors here:\n");
    file_t $;
    file_print_lines(&$, 243, 4);


    return 0;
}
```

**Build and run commands:**

1. In C:

   ```sh
   mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 \
       read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c -o bin/a && bin/a
   ```
2. In C++

   ```sh
   mkdir -p bin && g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 \
       read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c -o bin/a && bin/a
   ```

**Sample run cmd and output** (most lines in the middle deleted, since the bulk of the output is just a print out of the source code itself):

````
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c -o bin/a && bin/a
The size of the `file_t` struct is 2081016 bytes (2.081016 MB; 1.984612 MiB).
Max file size that can be read into this struct is 2000000 bytes or 10000 lines, whichever limit is hit first.

Loading file at path "read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c".
Printing the entire file:
num_chars to print = 15603
num_lines to print = 425
========== FILE START ==========
   1: /*
   2: This file is part of eRCaGuy_hello_world: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world
   3: 
   4: GS
   5: 2 Mar. 2022
   6: 
   7: Read a file in C into a C-string (array of chars), while also placing pointers to the start of each
   8: line into another array of `char *`. This way you have all the data plus the
   9: individually-addressable lines. Use static memory allocation, not dynamic, for these reasons:
  10: 1. It's a good demo.
  11: 1. It's faster at run-time since lots of dynamic memory allocation can add substantial overhead.
  12: 1. It's deterministic to use static memory allocation, making this implementation style good for
  13:    safety-critical, memory-constrained, real-time, deterministic, embedded devices and programs.
  14: 1. It can access the first character of any line in the file in O(1) time via a simple index into
  15:    an array.
  16: 1. It's extensible via dynamic memory allocation if needed.
  17: 
  18: STATUS: works!
  19: 
  20: To compile and run (assuming you've already `cd`ed into this dir):
  21: 1. In C:
  22: ```bash
  23: gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c -o bin/a && bin/a
  24: ```
  25: 2. In C++
  26: ```bash
  27: g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c -o bin/a && bin/a
  28: ```
  29: 

.
.
.
 406: //   300:
 407: //   301:     eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c -o bin/a && bin/a
 408: //   302:
 409: //   303:
 410: //   304: */
 411: //  =========== FILE END ===========
 412: //
 413: //  Printing just one line now:
 414: //   255:
 415: //
 416: //  Causing some intentional errors here:
 417: //   243: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 243 at index = 242.
 418: //   244: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 244 at index = 243.
 419: //   245: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 245 at index = 244.
 420: //   246: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 246 at index = 245.
 421: //
 422: //
 423: // OR, in C++:
 424: //
 425: // [SAME AS THE C OUTPUT]
=========== FILE END ===========

Printing just this 1 line number:
            file->line_array[i_write_line] = &(file->file_str[i_write_char]);

Printing 4 lines starting at this line number:
 256:             file->line_array[i_write_line] = &(file->file_str[i_write_char]);
 257:             i_write_line++;
 258:         }
 259: 

Causing some intentional errors here:
 243: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 243 at index = 242.
 244: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 244 at index = 243.
 245: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 245 at index = 244.
 246: ERROR in function file_print_line(): line_array contains NULL ptr for line_number = 246 at index = 245.
````

### References

(not a complete list by any means)

1. **[read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/read_file_into_c_string_and_array_of_lines.c)**, from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen
3. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror - shows a good usage example of
   `printf("File opening error: %s\n", strerror(errno));` if `fopen()` fails when opening a file.
4. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc

Answer (score 1):

Apart from saying this is far from an efficient solution, here's yours slightly modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_SIZE 1024
char** load_array(const char *fn) {

    char** fcontent = (char**)malloc(0);

    FILE * file = fopen(fn, "r");

    char line[MAX_SIZE];

    int i = 0;

    // read file line by line with fgets()
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        fcontent = (char**)realloc(fcontent, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        fcontent[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
        // this part I'm not sure of. maybe setting with fgets makes more sense.
        strcpy(fcontent[i], line);
        i++;
    }

    fcontent = (char**)realloc(fcontent, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    fcontent[i] = NULL;

    fclose(file);
    return fcontent;
}

int main()
{
    char **lines = load_array("test.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (lines[i])
        printf("%s", lines[i++]);

    i = 0;
    while (lines[i])
        free(lines[i++]);
    free(lines);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would you recommend as efficient? Which part of the code?

Comment: This also returns a segmentation fault for me.

Comment: do you have a "test.txt" file ?

Comment: yes I do have a file and I also check if the file exists anyway

Comment: No, accept my apologies because this is correct I was getting that segfault from another silly snippet.

Comment: No worries - the reason it is far from efficient is because of the many (re)allocations and unnecessary copies.  Now, efficient is very domain specific, if this is fast enough for your use case, then use it, but otherwise you would want to consider alternatives such as processing lines _as you read them_ or growing the `fcontent` by doubling the size each time so you don't reallocate for each line - or use a linked list of buffers. There are many many options, they depend on the size of your typical file for example, amongst many things.

Comment: That is exactly what I was going for. I was thinking about using the same array from the local function to pass it on other functions to process it. I didn't really think someone would call it efficient but now that I know that I'm relieved.

Comment: @OmerErbilgin, don't forget to upvote any helpful answer. Since you marked it as correct, that clearly means it helped you, so you should upvote it too. It inspires answerers to keep on answering.

Comment: @OmerErbilgin, on that note, I'll see if I can provide another answer later tonight, with an alternative approach.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I didn't know I could upvote with the amount of my reputation. Just learned I could and gave it right after. I think on what I said you should open a new question and maybe answer it too. Would be interesting to also use the same array with multiple files and dynamically storing end points with integer variables.

Comment: Why are you `malloc`ing size `0` via `(char**)malloc(0);`? From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc: `If size is zero, the behavior of malloc is implementation-defined. For example, a null pointer may be returned. Alternatively, a non-null pointer may be returned; but such a pointer should not be dereferenced, and should be passed to free to avoid memory leaks.`

Comment: I see: it's so you can pass it to `realloc()` later, and since you're not dereferencing it before the `realloc()`, I suppose it's ok.